# Best practice: weak reference to activity in static method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, weak-references

I need to reference an activity in several static methods. I'm curious to know the best practices to avoid memory leaks. Let's use examples:

Example 1:

```java
static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
   WeakReference<Activity> activityReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
   // ... Call activityReference.get() when needed, check if null...
}
```

Example 2:

```java
static void hideKeyboard(WeakReference<Activity> activityReference) {
   // ... Call activityReference.get() when needed, check if null...
}
```

So three questions:

1. Do example 1 or 2 make any difference?
2. I haven't seen methods being called this way much outside of subclasses of `Thread` or `AsyncTask`. Any reason why? Am I missing something?
3. If the weak reference is used in a `Thread` or `AsyncTask` inside one of those methods, could memory still leak?

Comment: `I haven't seen methods being called this way` start here. what are you hoping to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I'm using static methods to be called throughout the app, in different activities and fragments.

Comment: i get that, i'm asking why ? what do they do that you can't achieve within the actual activity or fragment

Comment: @a_local_nobody they can be done within each activity, but I would need to copy-paste the code in every one of them. Instead, I use a global "utility" class that includes methods to be called from anywhere. It allows the maintenance of the code in one unique place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't make a difference.  Garbage collection in Java works on the idea of GC roots.  If a variable is a GC root or references by a GC root (including transitively) it cannot be garbage collected.  Parameters to a function are a GC root-  until the function returns none of its parameters can be collected.  Since Activity is a parameter to your function, it will be uncollectable as long as that function is in the call stack.  Using a WeakReference won't speed it up.

Threads and AsyncTasks (which are just wrappers around Thread really) are slightly different.  Every running thread is also a GC root.  But threads can have a long lifetime and exist beyond the lifecycle of the object.   Here, using a WeakReference does possibly help because there isn't another reason it needs to be kept around (like the parameter in your sample).

Your example 2 is a bit better, it isn't blatantly unnecessary. But I question why its needed.  In general when doing a Thread the pattern should be:

```
run() {
   do_async_work()
   update_ui()
}

update_ui() {
  Activity activity = weakReference.get()
  if(activity == null) {
     return
  }

  //update the UI
}
```

Doing it like this will prevent a lot of problems like needing to check the weak reference a dozen times.

Comment: I got the Thread subclass pattern right but I wasn’t sure for simple static methods. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason to use `WeakReference` in a parameter passed to a method, unless this parameter is being **stored**. If the parameter is only used in the method, you can just pass in the `Activity` reference.

Comment: But if you pass the context/activity in a static class function then you will get the warning of a memory leak. So in this case you have to use weakreference of an activity to avoid any leaks.

Comment: @Tara please explain If you pass it as a parameter and you do not store it in a `static` class variable, there is no chance of a memory leak, so please show where/how you are getting this warning.

Comment: I am storing it in a public class static method.

Comment: @Tara yes, well, that is why you are getting the warning. As I said in my answer, there is no reason for `WeakReference` **unless the parameter is being stored**.

Comment: hmm yess. Sorry i misread.